# Checking whether ALE has finished running a linter

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

What Vim function can I call to determine whether ALE has finished running its linters yet? I want to update my statusline to show a "loading" message while they run, and hide the message when the linters are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [`ale#engine#IsCheckingBuffer(buffer)`](https://github.com/w0rp/ale/blob/cae40e1c347064bd3ab5eb4c04e9e357d3d82105/doc/ale.txt#L2382-L2386); the help explicitly mentions that *This function can be used for status lines, tab names, etc.*